# StyleCop for Resharper - Insert Method Header, how to disable line break after <param> tag

Tags: resharper, xml-documentation

How can I stop StyleCop for Resharper (or ReSharper itself) from adding a line break after the start ***param*** element tag and before the end tag when adding method header documentation.

From:-

```
/// <param name="name">
/// The name.
/// </param>
```

To:-

```
/// <param name="name">The name.</param>
```

I have unchecked everything that mentions line-break under the *XML Doc Comments* section to no avail but could not find another relevant section?

Comment: In the `XML Doc Comments`, is the value of `Line breaks after start-tag and before end-tag when element is longer than` higher than your line length?

Comment: Yes, the value is default, 2147483647, and the param text lengths are nowhere near that limit. (Typically less than 30 characters).

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour when ReSharper is disabled? You can do that by going in `Tools -> Options -> ReSharper -> Suspend Now`. You'll have to re-enable it manually after the test to get functionalities back.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? With ReSharper disabled the option to **Insert Method Header** would not be available?

Comment: It's just to test if ReSharper is responsible for your formatting problem. Once you'll have done the test, you can re-enable it. To add XML documentation to a method, you can type `///` above it and Visual Studio should add it.

Comment: I see, just tested, the formatting behaviour is from ReSharper generating the documentation. I'm using it in conjunction with the StyleCop extension.

Comment: I don't see an option **Insert Method Header** in ReSharper. You should look at StyleCop extension options (if there are) or test to disable it to see if the problem persits.

Comment: Apologies, it IS a feature of the extension, not ReSharper. No options are available within the extension so I guess I am out of luck.

Comment: I am actually looking for the same feature as the previous developers have used this style in our project. Have you found any workaround for this, @gibsoncarl?

Comment: I'm afraid not, using the snippet /// formats as expected so I just manually add the comments. (I have created some snippet templates as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio menu "Resharper" > "Options" go to "Tools" > "StyleCop" and check the box "Use single lines for declaration headers".

[Screenshot (link to imgur.com)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9rA7.png)

This will however apply to all documentation elements, not just param, like:

```
/// <summary>The send error.</summary>
/// <param name="errorId">The error id.</param>
/// <param name="type">The type.</param>
/// <param name="message">The message.</param>
```

Compared to the following, when the box is unchecked:

```
/// <param name="errorId">
/// The error id.
/// </param>
/// <param name="type">
/// The type.
/// </param>
/// <param name="message">
/// The message.
/// </param>
```

If you want it more custom than that I suspect you need adjust it manually after that.

Comment: Many thanks. This is certainly the lesser of evils if there are more than a couple of parameters.